# git pre-commit + mysqldump: cannot find path, not existing command

Tags: git, bash, hook, mysql

I have windows 7 but I think it doesn't count, because the hook uses git shell. I tried to dump my database by commit with the following code, but it did not work.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Refresh the SQL schema file for inclusion within the git commit

# If something fails, exit with status other than 0
set -e

# select dump directory
    cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
    cd WebShop/DataBase

# first, remove our original schema
rm -f backup.sql

# generate a new schema
mysqldump -u root --password=root webshopdb > backup.sql

# Add the schema to the next commit
git add backup.sql

# Exit success
exit 0
```

I've got 2 error messages:

The path doesn't exist, because the space in a directory name breaks it.

```
    cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

Cannot find command

```
    mysqldump -u root --password=root webshopdb > backup.sql
```

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: news:
I managed to get error messages from git bash (I tried first time with git gui, so I didn't get message)
It says, that cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) cannot found because there is a space character in one of the directory names contained by the path. :S And the mysqldump command cannot find neither. This will be a long day... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the errors, it creates the sql file, but still doesn't add it to the commit. I don't know why...

The fixed code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Refresh the SQL schema file for inclusion within the git commit

# If something fails, exit with status other than 0
set -e

# select dump directory
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"

# first, remove our original schema
rm -f "WebShop\DataBase\backup.sql"

# generate a new schema
exec "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" --skip-comments -u root --password=root webshopdb |sed 's$),($),\n($g' > "WebShop\DataBase\backup.sql"

# Add the schema to the next commit
git add "WebShop\DataBase\backup.sql"

# Exit success
exit 0
```

- If we have whitespace in the path we have to use it between double
  quotes.
- I used the exec and the full path of mysqldump.exe instead of
  the mysqldump command.
- Made some changes by mysqldump options:

  - skip comments (to prevent file change caused by creation time footer)
  - split insert into multiple lines by sed

Comment: If somebody says how to make the add working I'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: A created a runnable file from this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254186/mysqldump-from-executable-on-windows-7

A don't know why the add wasn't working. It's in every tutorial I found. I'll try it with the --no-verify param asap.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do this too, and came up with mixed results, but ultimately this does work. Maybe git has had a few updates since last year that fixed the problem? Maybe it's because I'm on a mac? Here's the pre-commit I use now. (Thanks to everyone's help)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Dump a fresh copy of the database
mysqldump -u root --password="password" myDB --skip-extended-insert > dump.sql
git add dump.sql
```

*Note: The `--skip-extended-insert` is not necessary to make any changes to the bash, I just like the way my SQL dumps can be tracked in git with that extra option added.*

**what seemed to matter was how I was running the git command**

If I ran `git` from the commandline, then there were no problems.

If I ran `git` via SourceTree, then there are errors [unless SourceTree is run from the commandline too.](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/140339/sourcetree-hook-failing-because-paths-don-t-seem-to-be-set-correctly?page=1#comment-141310)

Answer (score 0):

To debug sh, use

```
sh -x script
```

(comment **set -e**)

and you may source your rc file at the beginning to avoid using full paths :

```
source ~/.shrc
```

Comment: That's too many information for me. :-) I don't know bash scripting, and don't call the commit from console, so if the sh -x script prints something out in the console, I won't see it. I was thinking about a log file, or so. Hmm I try it out with cmd.exe, and I'll create a .bat file from the code, maybe something good happens to me :D

Comment: Have you tested with my 2th recommendation ?
If you have no .shrc file, see if you have .bashrc one.
sh -x can be ran by yourself to test your script in debug mode.

Comment: I think the main problem is that I have windows, not linux... (If you think the opposite, please tell me :D)

Comment: oO
So it's not your own script, and you took it somewhere on the web and hope black magic ?
Maybe you just need to install cygwin ?

Comment: Yepp, that's a copy paste code. I don't understand the unix magic. :-) Hmm I try it out, but I'm afraid it won't help :S For example the comment in windows bash is :: etc... If I have to process the file with a cygwin.exe, than I have to use absolute path to it, and to give them the git path, etc... I think it cannot be done that way...

Comment: The cygwin didn't work, but I have good news, the git hook works under the git shell, so I can user that commands. I'm trying out the code from git bash and I can print now text with echo :D now testing the part of the code, maybe it print out an error or so...

Comment: The "sh -x script" doesn't work because the hook file is running under git shell, not under unix shell ... Btw thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If git is in your path in your .profile/.bash_profile etc you shouldn't need to set it.  That said you are only "add"ing the file and not committing it.  After you add you need to run

```
 git commit -m "updated schema"
```

Comment: Committing in a pre commit will result infinite loop don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP already found his solution, but for anyone looking for a pre-commit hook for mysqldump, check this Gist out.. it should do the job for you: https://gist.github.com/wilcollins/dfa33ef20caf6dab5826

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# -e means exit if any command fails
DBHOST=address.to.your.server
DBUSER=username
DBPASS=password # do this in a more secure fashion
DBNAME=DBNAME
GITREPO=/where/is/your/repo
DUMP=$GITREPO/where/you/store/dumps
NEW=$DUMP/schema.sql
OLD=$NEW.old

DIR=$(pwd)
cd $GITREPO

mv $NEW $OLD

mysqldump -h $DBHOST -u $DBUSER -p$DBPASS $DBNAME --skip-dump-date --single-transaction > $NEW

# NOTE : the new schema.sql file & location need to be added to your GIT repo & ignore .old

if cmp -s $OLD $NEW; then
    echo Same
else
    echo Differ
    git commit $NEW -m "$DBNAME DB update"
    echo "schema+data committed"

    git push # assuming you have a remote to push to
    echo "schema+data pushed"
fi
cd $DIR
```